# Postfix Expression Calculator Validation

Tags: validation

I need this code to be edited slightly using a loop to tell the user that their input was incorrect and then let them retry typing in a post fix expression?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.println("Enter your two numbers and the operation with spaces between e.g 8 9 -");

        String calculation=scan.nextLine();

            String [] parts = calculation.split(" ");

        try{

            double part1 = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
            double part2 = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);

            double answer = 0;
            boolean incorrectOperation = false;
            String operation = parts[2];
            switch (operation) {
            case "+":
                answer = part1 + part2;
                    break;
            case "-":
                answer = part1 - part2;
                    break;
            case "*":
                answer = part1 * part2;
                    break;
            case "/":
                answer = part1 / part2;
                    break;
            default:
                incorrectOperation = true;
            }

            String ans;
            if(incorrectOperation) {
            ans = "Please use +, -, * or / for operation";
            } else {
        ans = String.valueOf(answer);
    }
              System.out.println(ans);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid expression " + calculation);
    }


}
}
```

It needs to have some sort of message output using 'System.out.println' to tell the user what they have type is incorrect